# SQL Server: How to select missing rows in table from another table?

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables like below:

**table1**:

```
StoreId SKU
------------
1       abc
2       abc
3       abc
1       xyz
4       xyz
```

**table2**:

```
 StoreId
 --------
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
```

I want to select missing storeid from the table1 which are in table 2. But condition is that in above example for SKU abc storeid 4 and 5 are missing and for sku xyz 2,3,5 are missing. So I want below table as output

```
SKU,ID
------
abc 4
abc 5
xyz 2
xyz 3
xyz 5
```

I am able to pull only the overall missing store which is 5 using below query.

```
 SELECT 
     SKU, t2.StoreId 
 FROM 
     @table1 t1 
 FULL OUTER JOIN
     @table2 t2 ON t1.StoreId = t2.StoreId 
 WHERE
     t1.StoreId IS NULL
```

Below is test create and insert query.

```
Declare @table1 As table
(
 StoreId varchar(4),
 SKU varchar(5)
)

Declare @table2 As table
(
 StoreId int
)
BEGIN
Insert Into @table1(SKU,StoreId) values('abc',1)
Insert Into @table1(SKU,StoreId) values('abc',2)
Insert Into @table1(SKU,StoreId) values('abc',3)
Insert Into @table1(SKU,StoreId) values('xyz',1)
Insert Into @table1(SKU,StoreId) values('xyz',4)
Insert Into @table2(StoreId) values(1)
Insert Into @table2(StoreId) values(2)
Insert Into @table2(StoreId) values(3)
Insert Into @table2(StoreId) values(4)
Insert Into @table2(StoreId) values(5)
END
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get a list of all skus and tables, and then show only rows which do not appear in table1:

```
select SKU, StoreID
from @table2 t2
cross join (select distinct sku from @table1) t1
where not exists (select 1 from @table1 table1 
                  where table1.SKU = t1.SKU 
                    and table1.StoreId = t2.StoreId)
```

Comment: Thank You So Much. You are a great help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution with the same result.

Syntax is very similar to the answer from @BeanFrog:

```
SELECT
  t3.SKU, t2.StoreID
FROM
  @table2 t2
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT distinct SKU
   FROM @table1) t3
LEFT JOIN
  @table1 t1 
ON
  t1.SKU = t3.SKU 
  and t1.StoreId = t2.StoreId
WHERE
  t1.sku is null
```